# X11/xlib.h giving me XClearWindow errors

Tags: c, linux, x11

I have this program written in C code. it is a fork of hsetroot. I took it then add a lot more options to it so one can manipulate the image and colors that is set to ones desktop. the user has more control over it. it compiled and installed with no errors whatsoever.

I did this on a 32 bit Debian Linux OS. then I went out and got me a dual core 64 bit laptop ($50) Install Linux 64 bit. took my program out to dust it off and maybe clean it up a bit more, just for GP (general purpose).

when i tried to compile it on the command line I now am getting errors and it will no longer compile. the code has not been changed whatsoever. therefore no error should be seen.

nevertheless I am getting this error than it fails to completely compile. the funnier thing about it if I use the -m32 arg i will get a different fail to compile error then if I use or DO NOT use the -m46 arg.

I compile using this command with or without the -m64 arg then get the following error.

```
 gcc `imlib2-config --cflags` `imlib2-config --libs` mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c -o myapp
```

then get this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclrRrBO.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XClearWindow'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO 
missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it tells me that the XClearWindow is NOT defined in the header file when it is. /usr/include/X11/xlib.h

```
extern int XClearWindow(
Display*        /* display */,
Window      /* w */
```

when I compile it using the  -m32 arg I get this error instead

```
/development/c/mhsetroot$ gcc -m32  `imlib2-config --cflags` `imlib2- config --libs` mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c -o myapp
```

I get this error

```
In file included from mhsetroot-v1.6.2.c:29:0:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:38:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or    directory #include <sys/types.h>
```

telling something is now wrong with the sys/types.h --

what gives -- the code has never been changed from when I had no problems doing this on a 32 bit Linux OS. but now on this 64 BIT Linux OS i am having problems. what is the real problem? because it is not my code.

Comment: The `undefined reference` error is _not_ a compile error, but a link error. It's nothing to do with the header, but means you need to add a library to the link line. You may want to examine the output of `imlib2 --libs` to see what it's giving you.

Comment: it seems to me to be a new problem (to me) as in 32 bit this link did not need to be added to the args on the command line now in 64 bit is does, where now I need to add -lX11 to the command line args @Useless thanks it works now

Comment: If it is solved either close the question or add an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the question title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. If no existing answer solves the problem, you can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I did that then this forum tells me I cannot accept my own answer that I know for a fact it right until the next day -- so then someone that didn't even check when I posted my answer decided  to get all I'm god on me - this is the only place I know of this different rule not to add SOLVED so people can see that for quick reference to check that one out first

Comment: @Useless: Yes, this place does have different rules than other places. You should be able to accept your own answer now if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

the command line arg that needs to be added is -lX11  to tell it to link X11 as well ... (not needed when i was running a 32 bit Linux, but is now needed in a 64 bit linux N.I.W. (No Idea Why) this gets rids of the "DSO missing from command line" link error. it now compiles with none of that --